# How to Create / Update Query using WSProxy method?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, query-definition

I am trying to create / Update Query Definition using SSJS WSProxy method.

This is my script:

```
<script runat="server" >
Platform.Load("core","1.1");

  var api=new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  var qd = {
    Name : "WS_Created_Query",
    CustomerKey : "myQueryDef124579",
    TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
    TargetType : "DE",
    Target : {
        Name : "Counts",
        CustomerKey : "Counts-Key"
    },
    QueryText : "SELECT * from errorlog"
};


var myDE=api.createItem("QueryDefinition",qd);

</script>
```

but this Script not working.. can someone helps to identify the error, please. (I have a feeling QueryDefinition is not the correct object name for this method.?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

QueryDefinition is the correct object for this. However, "Target" is not a property of the QueryDefinition object of the SOAP API. So if you'd just go ahead and replace "Target" with "DataExtensionTarget", that should resolve it.

Comment: This is incorrect, you should be using "Target"

Comment: Look at the SOAP API object for Query Definition. Target is not a property, but DataExtensionTarget is.